# TYPO3 7.6.2 fluid_styled_content remove div

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, fluid-styled-content

I use TYPO3 7.6.2 and fluid_styled_content. With Gridelements my Code look like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
  <div id="c8">
    <h6>Test</h6>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I remove the `"div id="?` If I use "css_styled_content" there is no problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The whole rendering is defined inside the fluid templates (as the extension name suggests). So you are able to overwrite the folder containing the layouts / templates and modify them to your needs.

In case of "fluid_styled_content" the configuration is done in TypoScript, so add `lib.fluidContent.layoutRootPaths.30 = /path/to/your/layouts`, copy the original layouts from `EXT:fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Layouts/` to your path and modify them to fit your needs.

In your case you have to remove the line:

```
<div id="c{data.uid}">
```

in all three layouts.

Further information are available at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/7.6/Changelog/7.3/Feature-66111-AddTemplaterootpathsSupportToCobjectFluidtemplate.html

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what i nedded!

Comment: Starting with version 8.7, this should be `lib.contentElement` instead of `lib.fluidContent`. https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/8.7/Changelog/8.7/Breaking-80412-NewSharedContentElementTyposcriptLibaryObjectForFluidStyledContent.html?highlight=fluidcontent#fluid-styled-content

Comment: This worked for me too in TYPO3 9.5. Fluid Styled Content only has one Layout now (`Default.hmtl`) (this was already the case in version 8.7), so there is only one `div` to remove. I copied that layout to my own extension and added the line `lib.contentElement.layoutRootPaths.30 = …` into my `…/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript` file. (Can use a number other than 30 as long as it is greater than 10.) I also had to include my extension after Fluid Styled Content in my static includes in the backend, instead of before

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel
Thanks for the hint. 
Works for me too, but I had to add

```
lib.fluidContent.templateRootPaths.30 = EXT:extension/Resources/Private/Templates/
```

to my configuration, because, in my case I want to edit Textmedia.html and thats in Templates folder.